# How to flip element (mesh)?

Tags: math, matrix, 3d, three.js

I would like to flip my mesh over all axes. I have two excatly the same meshes, but I would like one to rotate (flip) so that It faces another ?

What is the correct transformation, do I have to do rotation, or do I have to somehow flip matrix?

Here is the image what I am trying to do:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG2uq.png

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Scale model by -1 in the axis you want the mirroring.

Comment: Faces might need flipping too.

Comment: @gaitat: Thank you, this kind of worked - but I've lost the position now, whole mesh moved a little bit. I would like it to stay at excatly the same place, just flipped.

Comment: @Zaay that means your model is not centered around LCS(0,0,0) or you are flipping mesh in GCS instead of LCS (local/global coordinate system) either fix that or take middle point from mesh before flipping `p0` (GCS), then after flipping `p1` (GCS) and translate the mesh by `(+/-)(p0-p1)` (GCS) vector. the mid point will not change position so choose it as you need ...